# Insert value before user info

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

so I'm trying to insert 2 digits before the users saved info gets filled in

I'm using the following code:

```
$("#billingExpirationYear").val(userInfo.exp_year);
```

I'd like to add "20"" before ".val(userInfo.exp_year);", any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: what is userInfo.exp_year?

Comment: It's a chrome extension so thats info saved by the user in the plugin that gets autofilled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#billingExpirationYear').val('20' + userInfo.exp_year.toString());
```

Comment: Thanks, but I can't get it to work, I have added a jfiddle that will probably make this easier to understand http://jsfiddle.net/eu16gcky/

Comment: at which time do you want the value added? at form submission?

Comment: As soon as the the form loads

Comment: or do you want to have the select default to the value from `userInfo.exp_year`?

Comment: userInfo.exp_year is the settings so a user can only add (YY) 17,18,19..etc so I need to add 20 to complete this particular form

Comment: you might want to: `$('#billingExpirationYear').val('20' + userInfo.exp_year.toString())`; see: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/eu16gcky/4/)